Facing error in springboot crud operation
i am working in springboot crud operation after i completed the operation when i am going to run the application it will shows like this error"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure"
i am trying to do a basic crud operation in springboot and expectiong the proper http responses. But it will not work as expected

Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Your MySQL database server has been lost or could not be established. This happen due to various reasons, like database server not running or misconfiguration of the connection settings.
Check Database Server Status: Ensure that the MySQL database server is running . check MySQL command line client weather MySQL is running or not. if not then you can turn it on manually from Services. (find mysql service and start it)
Double-check the connection settings in your application's configuration file (e.g., application.properties or application.yml).make sure that your hostname, port, username, and passwords are correct.
